# Does this implementation of a move constructor throw away move semantics?

Tags: c++, move-semantics

If I have a class `C` like so:

```
class C {
    std::string s;

public:
    C(std::string&  s) : s(s) {}
    C(std::string&& s) : C(s) {}
};
```

Am I throwing away move semantics by calling the `string&` constructor from the `string&&` constructor?

Comment: I'm not familiar with C++11, but in this case, isn't the move constructor simply redundant?

Comment: @stakx Move constructors are basically just faster copy constructors, but they only work if the caller is willing to destroy the object being moved from. So no, they do different things.

Comment: C has no move nor copy-ctor in this code outside the default-provisions, so I'm not sure what you're talking about.

Comment: What are the "benefits of perfect forwarding"? I think what you are really asking is whether you are throwing away move semantics.

Comment: @WhozCraig Wow, you're right. I got turned around in my head somehow. I should reword my question.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes, that is what I'm asking.

Comment: @juanchopanza I'm floundering here, if you know how to word my question properly please edit.

Comment: Your question appears worded correctly now. And the short answer, yes, you're tossing out your move-semantics. If I get time to write up a formal answer I will do so unless someone tosses up a similar example of how/why this is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're throwing out your move semantics. The most immediate method I can proffer to demonstrate how is by example. This is the sanest thing I could come up with so I hope it is clear what is going on.

Consider this:

```
#include <iostream>

struct S
{
    int x;

    S() :x(1) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';}
    S(const S& s) : x(s.x) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';}
    S(S&& s) : x(std::move(s.x)) { ++x, s.x=0; std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';}
    ~S() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ':' << x << '\n';}
};

class C {
    S s;

public:
    C(S& s) : s(s) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';}
    C(S&& s) : C(s) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }
    ~C() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';}
};

int main()
{
    C c{S{}};
}
```

**Output**

```
S::S()
S::S(const S &)
C::C(S &)
C::C(S &&)
S::~S():1
C::~C()
S::~S():1
```

Note that *two* instances of `S` are constructed, *neither* of them via move. Any `S` that is "moved" to an intended target will have `0` printed for `x`. None do. The first `S` is the initial temporary from `S{}`; the second is the copy made from invoking `C(C&)` via the `C(C&&)` initializer list. When this code is finished, two fully constructed `S` exist by the time we start running down the destructor chain.

Now look at this, the identical code, but employing move-semantics on the `s` member:

```
#include <iostream>

struct S
{
    int x;

    S() :x(1) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';}
    S(const S& s) : x(s.x) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';}
    S(S&& s) : x(std::move(s.x)) { ++x, s.x=0; std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';}
    ~S() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ':' << x << '\n';}
};

class C {
    S s;

public:
    C(S& s) : s(s) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';}
    C(S&& s) : s(std::move(s)) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }
    ~C() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';}
};

int main()
{
    C c{S{}};
}
```

**Output**

```
S::S()
S::S(S &&)
C::C(S &&)
S::~S():0
C::~C()
S::~S():2
```

Two instances of `S` are still constructed, but the latter is via move-construction, sucking up the first one to do so. When we start destroying all this stuff only one of the `S` instances is still valid; the other is dead via move-out.

Long story short, you're shooting yourself if your goal is moving. I *hope* that helps, though I'm totally willing to toss it if it doesn't.

Comment: For those confused about what `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` is, as I was, [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html) is some documentation.

Comment: @anthropomorphic It is *incredibly* helpful with templates, btw.

Comment: I find this very difficult to follow, but it is helpful, thank you.

Comment: Note that `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` is a gcc extension. Use `__func__` if you don't have access to it.

Comment: @anthropomorphic dont' concentrate on the macros as much as the *output*. Note the move-constructor of the member is *not* invoked in the first example that mimics your code, but *is* invoked in the second. Ultimately that was the point I was trying to get across.

Comment: @WhozCraig Not to knit pick, but hopefully to increase your knowledge: as stated [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html) (bottom of the page), `These identifiers are not preprocessor macros.`

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, I did eventually come to understand that. It just took me a while, and I'm still a little confused about some of the program flow.

Comment: @anthropomorphic sure. At this point i'm just going to drop the answer anyway, The intent, which I hoped was clear as crystal (demonstrating the member move-ctor is NOT invoked when delegating to the copy-ctor) has officially been lost in the otherwise-unimportant methods chosen for printing a function name. I'll leave it up for another hour or so so anyone that cares to snapshot it can do so.

Comment: Oh please don't. Obviously you have the right to do so, but I hope you chose not to, as this is the only helpful answer to this post.

Comment: @anthropomorphic I should probably have mentioned that a member with an `x` value of `0` is one that has been "moved" (it was the source of a move) and thus is no longer "valid". And a member that has an `x` value *greater* than `1` was the *target* of a move-construction. That would probably help explain the output you see considerably.

Answer (score 0):

This is not what is referred to when people mention "perfect forwarding." This is simply a move constructor calling a copy constructor (which is what I assume you meant). This is perfect forwarding:

```
class Foo{
public:
    template<typename TBar> Foo(TBar&& bar): m_str(std::forward<TBar>(bar)){}

private:
    std::string m_str;
};
```

What is going on here is that, because of template argument deduction and reference-collapsing rules, TBar&& is what is known as a "universal reference," which means that it could resolve its type to `TBar`, `TBar&`, or `TBar&&` (you can also add `const` and `volatile` in the mix). `std::forward` simply does as its name says, and "forwards" whatever TBar resolves to (preserves its deduced type) to the string's constructor.

Comment: Thats not a valid move ctor since, first, thats not a move ctor, is a perfect forwarding ctor to initialize your member directly bypassing the member arguments. The compiler generates a default move ctor for Foo in this case. Your answer has nothing to do with Foo move semantics

Comment: @Manu343726: ... -1, really? The author changed his title; it originally mentioned "perfect forwarding" and not move semantics. Hence my post about perfect forwarding.

Comment: If the author changed the question, update your answer accordingly. I had no idea the question was edited, I only have seen an answer non related at all with move semantics. Again, update the answer

Comment: Anybody care to explain the differences between move ctor and perfect forwarding ctor?

Comment: @Zsolt One difference is that the move constructor will get chosen over the perfect forwarding one when the types match.

Comment: @Zsolt Hoping I say this right for fear of juan's wrath (a daily occurrence for me) a PF-ctor is a template ctor with deduced types that collapse to the proper reference. A MV-ctor is a ctor with rvalue-reference parameter(s) for moving data out rather than copying it. Given both if a move-ctor properly matches  (you really are sending an rvalue-ref), it will be chosen over a PF-deduced ctor. I probably still butchered that, so juan, be gentle =P